# How can I get my iPhone to automatically download podcasts I have subscribed to?

Tags: iphone, ios, podcasts, podcasts.app

I am using the standard podcast app that comes with iOS 7.  I have subscribed to about 8-9 different podcasts.  Commonly I will take my phone with me when I leave the apartment, and then when I get on the subway I will attempt to listen to a podcast.  Invariably, the podcast won't play because no cellular connection is available.  To solve this issue I have indicated through the podcast app that I would like episodes to be automatically downloaded when they become available.  However, they don't get automatically downloaded.  This absolutely infuriates me.

Comment: Are you closing Podcasts via multitasking? This will stop it from running in the background.

Comment: I may be doing this.  I'll have to make sure I leave it open for a day or two and observe the behavior.

Comment: Yes, podcasts won't refresh in the background unless the Podcasts app is actually running. You get notified of new emails even when the Mail app is not running, so I think Apple should make Podcasts work the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, check the "Refresh Podcast" option and set it to every hour. 
Also, set Auto-Downloads to ALL

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the "Refresh Podcast" set to an appropriate interval? I.E. The frequency with which you would like it to query the podcast server for new episodes.

Comment: Yes.  It is set to refresh every hour.